# Removing a value in an object based on if it contains a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, filter

a fairly simple question today.

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var buttonLogos = { 
adcraft: [".","..","1.png","2.png","3.png"],
ferries: [".","..","1.png","2.png"]
}
```

and I'm looking for a quick way to remove the entries at the beginning with the dots, I would usually just filter out anything with a dot, but I can't because the strings I want contain a .png

it might be a solution to filter out the first two entries, because they will always be "." and ".." but alas I'm not sure how to even do that.

(jQuery is encouraged)

I would love some help! Thanks.

Comment: You can do splice(2) on each property value which is array.

Comment: Ahh, wrong. You have to do splice(0, 2) which will remove the first two items. For example: `for (var prop in buttonLogos) {
    buttonLogos[prop].splice(0, 2);
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i in buttonLogos){
    buttonLogos[i] = buttonLogos[i].filter(function(i){
        return !i.match(/^\.{1,2}$/);
    });
}
```

Comment: You should note that ``Array.filter`` is not available in IE8 and below.

Comment: I should... but you've done it for me - and it's a Saturday evening and I'm drunk already so IE8 can go and swivel :P

Comment: That makes two of us! Screw IE 8!

Answer (score 0):

You can use js regex as follows,

```
buttonLogos.adcraft = $(buttonLogos.adcraft).filter(function(i,val){return val.match(/[^\.]/);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Filters as mentioned in other answers or a combination of indexOf and splice would also work.

```
   var adcraft = [".","..","1.png","2.png","3.png"];
    var elems_to_rm = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < adcraft.length; i++) {
        if (adcraft[i].indexOf('.') === 0) {
            elems_to_rm.push(adcraft[i]); 
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < elems_to_rm.length; i++) {
        var index = adcraft.indexOf(elems_to_rm[i]);
        adcraft.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try manually. Any number of items can be deleted from the array by specifying just two
arguments: the position of the first item to delete and the number of items to delete. For
example, splice(0, 2) deletes the first two items.